# Получение размеров загруженной картинки

Tags: javascript

Реализую загрузку картинки и мне нужно знать размеры полученной картинки (под размерами подразумевается высота и ширина картинки).
Для реализации использую getBoundingClientRect(), но при загрузке картинки, изначально показывает дефолтные размеры блока (установленные стилями - 250px). После загрузки следующего файла, показывает уже как раз таки корректные размеры того, файла который загружал первым.

Код:

```
const previewImage = document.querySelector('#preview');

inputImage.onchange = function(){
  if (this.files && this.files[0]){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      previewImage.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
      };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    this.style.display = 'none';
    console.log(previewImage.getBoundingClientRect())
    }
  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После получения размера загружаю другую картинку, и получаю уже корректные размеры нужной мне картинки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Возможно есть какие то особенности у данного метода?

Comment: Поясните, вам нужны размеры исходного изображения (из данных), или размеры элемента картинки? И вы в консоль выводите раньше, чем src задаёте.

Comment: @Pavel Grishaev
Интересует размер элемента картинки, для дальнейшей работы с ней. Понял суть ошибки, и поставил в onload вывод в консоль, только все равно размеры не корректные получаются почему то. Пишет что высота картинки такая же как и ширина)

Comment: Не знаю поможет или нет: у картинки есть своё событие `onload`, сначала на него нужно обработчик задать (и в нём что-то уже делать), а под ним задавать `src`. Задание `src` не означает мгновенное применение картинки, так как её ещё нужно скачать по сети (сам элемент картинки её скачивает ещё или берёт из памяти). Если это не поможет, значит размер картинки действительно такой квадратный и нужно смотреть в какой последовательности применяются действия и стили.

Comment: @Pavel Grishaev, так в коде присутствует обработка события onload от класса FileReader.  Как раз таки внутри и идет назначение src для превью. Просто размер картинки указывается странный.  
Дефолтный размер там вообще 660х447